# Polling from ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a data structure like `Map<Key, Set<Value>>`. I'm trying to implement the following scenario:

1. Several producers update this map adding new values either to already existing keys or to new keys (in which case new map entries are created).
2. A consumer periodically *polls* some limited number of entries from the map and passes them to processor.

Here's my take:

```
private static final MAX_UPDATES_PER_PASS = 100;

private final ConcurrentHashMap<Key, Set<Value>> updates = new ConcurrentHashMap<Key, Set<Value>>();

@Override
public void updatesReceived(Key key, Set<Value> values) {
    Set<Value> valuesSet = updates.get(key);
    if (valuesSet == null){
        valuesSet = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<Value, Boolean>());
        Set<Value> previousValues = updates.putIfAbsent(key, valuesSet);
        if (previousValues != null){
            valuesSet = previousValues;
        }
    }
    valuesSet.addAll(values);
}

private class UpdatesProcessor implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int updatesProcessed = 0;
        Map<Key, Set<Value>> valuesToProcess = new HashMap<Key, Set<Value>>();
        Iterator<Map.Entry<Key, Set<Value>>> iterator = updates.entrySet().iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext() && updatesProcessed < MAX_UPDATES_PER_PASS) {
            Map.Entry<Key, Set<Value>> next = iterator.next();
            iterator.remove(); // <-- here 
            Key key = next.getKey();
            Set<Value> values = valuesToProcess.get(key);
            if (values == null){
                values = new HashSet<Value>();
                valuesToProcess.put(key, values);
            }
            values.addAll(next.getValue());
            updatesProcessed++;
        }
        if (!valuesToProcess.isEmpty()){
            process(valuesToProcess);
        }
    }
}
```

The method `updatesRecevied()` is called by producers of values from arbitrary threads. The `UpdatesProcessor` is scheduled for periodic execution through `ScheduledExecutorService`, so it too can be called from arbitrary threads.

Every single value should be processed exactly **once**. No more no less. I don't care if a value gets processed sooner or later, but eventually it should.

I want it to be fast and furious, so I don't want to `synchronize` everything up.

This clumsy code with the iterator in the `UpdatesProcessor` serves one single goal which could be easily achieved if there was something like `ConcurrentHashMap.poll()`. But there isn't.

So, to the questions. First, is this guaranteed to work or not? After I call `iterator.remove()` the entry is removed from the map, and every additional values would go to the new entry's set, right?

And second, am I complicating things? Is there a common approach to (data structure for) this kind of scenario?

Comment: It looks like you need a cache and you're building it manually with the ConcurrentHashMap, am I right?

Comment: Have you considered using [ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html)? It may not help a great deal but you should get a more predictable iteration. At least you have a `pollFirstEntry()` method.

Comment: @luiggi I wouldn't call it a cache, it's more like producer/consumer situation.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Well, `ConcurrentSkipListMap` would certainly save me a couple of lines of code and make thing slightly easier, but it would incur some performance overhead maintaining the order, which I don't care about. I don't care about predictable iteration either. I only care that **every** value be eventually processed. And only **once**.